# How to disable “Press tab to replace highlighted range” message in ReSharper 8?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper

When I write a method call and open bracket, and then get a tooltip to parameters of method. It's great.

Then I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to get a list of possible parameters. The tooltip with method parameters is moved up and an IntelliSence hint is opened down. This is also fine. However, the parameters are covered up by an uninformative message: *"Press tab to replace highlighted range"*. See a figure below:

[image: “Press tab to replace highlighted range” message]

It's really annoying. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reverse engineered the Resharper and found a configuration setting that manages a display of *“Press tab to replace highlighted range”* tooltip. This parameter is:

```
<s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/Housekeeping/IntellisenseHousekeeping/HintUsed/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
```

You could add this line in any configuration file and Resharper will disable the tooltip. I use the *“This computer”* configuration file:

`%AppData%\JetBrains\ReSharper\vAny\GlobalSettingsStorage.DotSettings`

Comment: Doesn't work for me with Resharper 8.0.2000.2660 and VS 2012.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not check Resharper version now. I'm on vacation, far away from the computer with Visual Studio:) Maybe other settings of your Resharper affect this behavior. If you share configuration files of Resharper, I will try to help you next week.

Comment: @sdds, I use Resharper 8.0.2000.2660 and VS 2012 too. It works fine for me. Probably the problem is another settings of your configuration file.

Comment: Turns out I've accidentally put the provided HintUsed setting after the closing xml element in the configuration file. Your solution actually works fine - thank you.